# Resize UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, sdwebimage, icarousel

I'm uring iCarossel with SDWebImage. Everything works just fine but when the image size is too big it just goes out of the screen.

Following is the snippet where image view is generated

```
view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

[((UIImageView *)view) setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pizzatower.com/img/icons/Pizza-icon.png"]];
//        [((UIImageView *)view) setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.rivercitypizza.com/PepperoniPizza-full.jpg"]];

view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 256);
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:10];
label.tag = 1;
[view addSubview:label];
```

I tried changint the `frame` attribute but nothing changes. Could someone point me out how to resize the image and keep it within the size of the screen?

Comment: may be you have to set the uiimageview  property contentMode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;` your image will be scaled to fit inside the frame.

Comment: How do I include this in my code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316634/how-to-cache-image-and-scale-it-correctly

Answer (score 2):

1. Set Your UIImageView ContentMode

   YourImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
2. Use this code

Write this line in your code.

```
UIImage *ResizeImage=[self resizeImage:YourMainUIImage resizeSize:CGSizeMake(100,100)];
```

Add add this method in your ViewController

```
-(UIImage *) resizeImage:(UIImage *)orginalImage resizeSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGFloat actualHeight = orginalImage.size.height;
    CGFloat actualWidth = orginalImage.size.width;

    float oldRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float newRatio = size.width/size.height;
    if(oldRatio < newRatio)
    {
        oldRatio = size.height/actualHeight;
        actualWidth = oldRatio * actualWidth;
        actualHeight = size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        oldRatio = size.width/actualWidth;
        actualHeight = oldRatio * actualHeight;
        actualWidth = size.width;
    }

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,actualWidth,actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [orginalImage drawInRect:rect];
    orginalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return orginalImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
  UIImage *resizedImage = [self imageWithImage:self.image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1024)];

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)imagee scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [imagee drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```